# The pages include writing function with parameter

Tags: java, jsf, parameter-passing

Another example of a file into the bottom of a button and a function parameter for ActionListener would like to run.

for example;

Maintoolbar.xhtml

```
<p:commandButton id="warnButton" value="#{BtnWarn}" actionListener="#{action}" update="messages" rendered="#{render2}"/>
```

Index.xhtml:

```
<ui:include src="MainToolbar.xhtml">
     <ui:param name="BtnWarn" value="Uyarı Mesajı"/>
     <ui:param name="Alisten" value="#{mesajlar.addWarn}"/>
     <ui:param name="render2" value="true"/>
</ui:include>
```

measajlar.java

```
@ManagedBean(name="mesajlar")
@SessionScoped

public class MessageController implements Serializable
{
   public void addWarn(ActionEvent actionEvent) 
   {
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Invalid password length");
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            context.addMessage(null, message);
   }
}
```

According to the data above, I wanted to do;

damn buttons in a page will only include these buttons in the page and there I wanted çalıştıracağım related functions. So if Maintoolbar.xhtml which page I want to run it, type its function within the Button.

a page of the function = aClass.save
function b = bClass.delete page.

parameters include which page is the same button, I wrote a while at the same time the delete button will save somewhere.

Comment: I failed to find a question here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ui:param name="Alisten" value="#{mesajlar.addWarn}"/> = fail code
<ui:param name="Alisten" value="#{mesajlar.addWarn("in fnc parameters")}"/> = Succes code
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using action instead of actionListener parameter as actionListener refers to JavaScript while action calls regular http request.